# Unable to locate ldaptive schema in CAS 4.2.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cas

I am new to the CAS setup, started using CAS 4.2.x version. With help of the below , doing the setup. 
[https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html][1]

After adding bean reference "http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext" in the deployerConfigcontext.xml, getting the error

**`Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring Namespace handler for xml schema namespace [http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext]`**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:ldaptive="http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
        http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using CAS 3.5.2 and was facing the same issue ..... the below workaround worked for me. You can give it a shot and see if it works for you as well.

Add the following dependency in your pom.xml file

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
         <artifactId>cas-server-support-ldap</artifactId>
         <version>${cas.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

then remove the below lines from your deployerConfigcontext.xml

```
xmlns:ldaptive="http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext"
http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext.xsd
```

In your deployerConfigcontext.xml remove the ldaptive declaration and replace it with the below format.

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
              <!-- DO NOT enable JNDI pooling for context sources that perform LDAP bind operations. -->
              <property name="pooled" value="false"/>

              <!--
                Although multiple URLs may defined, it's strongly recommended to avoid this configuration
                since the implementation attempts hosts in sequence and requires a connection timeout
                prior to attempting the next host, which incurs unacceptable latency on node failure.
                A proper HA setup for LDAP directories should use a single virtual host that maps to multiple
                real hosts using a hardware load balancer.
              -->
              <property name="url" value="your-ldap-url" />

              <!--
                Manager credentials are only required if your directory does not support anonymous searches.
                Never provide these credentials for FastBindLdapAuthenticationHandler since the user's
                credentials are used for the bind operation.
              -->
              <property name="userDn" value="your-userDn-info"/>
              <property name="password" value="password-for-your-userDn"/>

              <!-- Place JNDI environment properties here. -->
              <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
                <map>
                  <!-- Three seconds is an eternity to users. -->
                  <entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout" value="3000" />
                  <entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout" value="3000" />

                  <!-- Explained at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/auth.html -->
                  <entry key="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple" />
                </map>
              </property>
            </bean>
```

Also in your deployerConfigcontext.xml remove your ldapAuthenticationHandler bean and replace it with the following

```
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler"
              p:filter="your-ldap-filter"
              p:searchBase="your-search-base"
              p:contextSource-ref="contextSource"
              p:ignorePartialResultException="true" />
```

Please note that i am using CAS 3.5.2 so you might have to make some more changes ...